# Mognid caches partially loaded objects in identity map

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid3

I'm using mongoid 3 and found the following issue:

Lets say we have a user and he got many posts.

so

```
class User
  has_many :posts
class Post
  field :name
  belongs_to :user
```

ignore the missing mongoid::document .

I'm using rails so I got identity map.

Lets say user want to edit one of his posts.

I want to make sure on server side that the post is actually belongs to the user.

I write the following code:

```
unless current_user.post_ids.include? post_id
  raise "invalid request"
```

After the check I write

```
 Post.find post_id
```

If I inspect this post I see it has only the id field loaded.

I guess its because when I asked for post_ids, it was lazy loaded to identity map but fetched only the id field from db.

My question is how to handle this?

I will get name == nil unless call reload on the post object.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply turn off the identity map for this particular query.

```
Mongoid.unit_of_work(disable: :current) do
  <<Query>> -- Will hit DB now
end
```

Also, Don't rely and test too much of this stuff in debugger / Rails console. It won't give correct results as the Identity map clears only after each request. So the results are not very evident from  the debugger.